# XSLT - Select all siblings of a given tag until another tag (again)

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given the following XML, I want to select every potential element between "First heading" and "Second heading", these heading elements excluded.
I am not sure what version of XSLT I can use (I'm modifying a sheet run by a proprietary app...)

```
<body>
  <h1 class="heading1">Some title</h1>
  <p class="bodytext">Some text.</p>

  <p class="sectiontitle">First heading</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Want that.</p>
  <div>
    <p class="bodytext">Want that too!</p>
  </div>

  <p class="sectiontitle">Second heading</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Some text</p>

  <p class="sectiontitle">Third heading</p>
  ...
</body>
```

Expected:

```
<p class="bodytext">Want that.</p>
<div>
  <p class="bodytext">Want that too!</p>
<div>
```

I know that `p class="sectiontitle">First heading</p>`:

- will always be of the `sectiontitle` class.
- will always contain `First heading`.
- does not have to be first p of this class, its position is unknown.

I also now that I will stop once I find `<p class="sectiontitle">Could be any title</p>` (so based on class only)

I have seen the other similar posts about this kind of problems, and I still can't crack my case...

What I have tried, amongst other things:

```
//*[(preceding-sibling::p/text()="First heading") and (not(following-sibling::p[@class="sectiontitle"]))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a great way to answer my own question using ids.

Let's say you want to select the following siblings of the current tag (a sectiontitle in my example), until you find any element that has a 'title' looking class, so for instance `paragraphtitle` or `sectiontitle`:

```
 <xsl:variable name="thisgid" select="generate-id(.)" />
 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[not(@class='sectiontitle' or @class='paragraphtitle')]
                              [generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class='sectiontitle'][1]) = $thisgid]"/>
```

That has solved many problems in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following XPath expression (updated to avoid selecting the 2nd `sectiontitle` element) :

```
//p[@class='sectiontitle' and .='First heading']
 /following-sibling::*[
    preceding-sibling::p[@class='sectiontitle'][1] = 'First heading'
    and not(self::p/@class = 'sectiontitle')
 ]
```

Basically, the XPath returns `following-sibling` elements of the `First Heading` element, where the nearest preceding sibling `'sectiontitle'` is the `First Heading` element itself.

Comment: Thank you for the (quick) answer. It is a major leap forward but still does not return what is expected.

Comment: After tinkering with your answer I also noticed that the first heading does not have to be p[@class='sectiontitle'][1] but must be identified by the 2 critiria I mentioned. This thing is tricky.

Comment: @Flag don't you think the expression `preceding-sibling::p[@class='sectiontitle'][1] = 'First heading'` covers both criteria?

Comment: @Flag you are welcome! As an aside, XSLT has features like `current()` and variables that you can utilize to avoid constructing too complex/long XPath expression -if only the question was posted with more XSLT context in it :D

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more straightforward, meaning you can specify between which two headings you want the output :

```
//p[@class='sectiontitle' and text()='Second heading']/preceding-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::p[@class='sectiontitle'][1] = 'First heading']
```

For example if you want to get output between '`Second heading`' and '`Third heading`' just change '`Second heading`' to '`Third heading`' and '`First heading`' to '`Second Heading`' in the above expression

Comment: That's pretty cool too, I might give it a go, and I'm sure other people will be interested as well. Thank you for your answer.